# Redux observable - resolving multiple actions - async

Tags: reactjs, redux, rxjs, redux-observable

I'm trying to inject a third party script onto a page and once its loaded initialise a video player.

I want to be able to have multiple video players on any page so I have some logic to check whether the script is already loaded and fire a different actions depending on whether it is or not.

My "script loading" helper looks like this:

```
  /**
   * injectScript - Inject player script into page
   * @param {String} id - script tag id
   * @param {String} src - script src
   * @return {Promise} - script load callback
   */
  injectScript (id, src) {
    return new Promise(resolve => {
      if (!document.getElementById(id)) {
        const script = document.createElement('script');
        script.setAttribute('id', id);
        script.type = 'text/javascript';
        script.src = src;
        document.body.appendChild(script);

        script.onload = () => resolve('script-loaded');
      } else {
        resolve('script-exists');
      }
    });
  }
```

I then have an epic which calls this helper and fires an action depending on the outcome. The epic looks like this:

```
/**
 * loadPlayerScript
 * @param {Object} action$ - action observable
 * @param {Object} store - redux store
 * @param {Object} dependencies - injected dependencies
 * @return {Object} - action observable
 */
export default function loadPlayerScript (action$, store, { scriptLoaderHelper }) {
  return action$.ofType(PLAYER_SCRIPT_LOAD)
    .switchMap(action => Observable.fromPromise(scriptLoaderHelper.injectScript(action.data.id, action.data.script)))
    .map(data => {
      if (data === 'script-loaded') {
        return playerScriptSuccess();
      }

      return playerScriptExists();
    })
    .catch(error => Observable.of(playerScriptFailure(error)));
}
```

The problem:

The `PLAYER_SCRIPT_LOAD` gets fired twice (I can validate this in Redux dev tools), this is expected. Whats happening though is the epic is only resolving the promise once (and it only fires one of the actions in the map). How do I get the epic to fire the actions for each promise resolve?

I'm sure its something super simple that I'm overlooking but any helps is appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

Change `switchMap` to `mergeMap` to avoid cancellation:

> The main difference between switchMap and other flattening operators is the cancelling effect. On each emission the previous inner observable (the result of the function you supplied) is cancelled and the new observable is subscribed. You can remember this by the phrase switch to a new observable.

source: https://www.learnrxjs.io/operators/transformation/switchmap.html